# Parent element not getting child function call arguments

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm almost there, missing just one simple thing. I'm modyfing state of parent with a child that has the function passed. The problem is that when the child calls the function passed from parent with an argument, that argument is not being catched in the parent's method.

Parent:

```
export default class GameList extends Component {
  constructor({ navigation }) {
    super();
    this.navigation = navigation;
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.state = {
      test: 0,
    }

  updateState(filteredResults) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(filteredResults),
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.background}>
        <Header updateState={() => { this.updateState() }} dataSet={this.dataSet} />
      </View >
    )
  }

};
```

Child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            const filteredResults = this.filterRows(text, this.props.dataSet);
            debugger;
            this.props.updateState(filteredResults);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  filterRows(searchText, dataSet) {
    return dataSet.filter((record) => record.title.includes(searchText));
  }
}


export default Header;
```

'filteredResults' in parent is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is you are calling that method with no arguments:

```
updateState={() => { this.updateState() }} //here
```

Instead of that write it like this:

```
updateState={this.updateState}
```

And use `updateState` function like this:

```
updateState = (filteredResults) =>  {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
        dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(filteredResults),
     }));
 }
```

Or another alternative is just define the binding in the constructor:

```
this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
```

then use that function like this:

```
updateState={this.updateState}

updateState(filteredResults) {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
        dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(filteredResults),
     }));
 }
```

Comment: It works perfectly mate, I just don't get why updateState = () => {} works, and regular updateState() {} doesn't ? That's the last thing in that subject I don't get

Comment: when you write `updateState={this.updateState}` means you are passing the reference of that `function` and actual function will get called from child component with parameter, and `arrow function` is used to maintain the context, it will work without `arrow function` also but in that case you will no be able to use `this` inside that function. To test that remove `arrow` and remove the `this.setState` simply do `console.log(parameter);` it will print the proper parameter passed from child.

Comment: Got it! I understand now, thank you! Answer accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Header updateState={this.updateState} dataSet={this.dataSet} />
```

You create a new function and don't pass the param to the inner function each time.

```
<Header updateState={(filteredResults) => this.updateState(filteredResults)} dataSet={this.dataSet} />
```

But that's pointless. Just go with the first way.

Comment: You're right about why it's not working mate, just I don't think the 2nd option is pointless as it allows you to keep the context in the child without the binding (see 1st answer). Thanks tho!